# alias. How to optimize?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

in my policies folder I have product_policy.rb

```
class ProductPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  def update?
    creator? || admin?
  end

  alias create? update?

  def manage?
    creator?
  end

  def destroy?
    update?
  end

  def color?
    update?
  end

  etc.etc.
```

As you can see, it was used alias to avoid to add also

```
  def create?
    update?
  end
```

But few lines beyound there are destroy? and color? that made the same thing.
I tried to edit alias in this way

alias create? destroy? color? update?

but it doesn't work.

How to optimize this alias?

Answer (score 0):

There are some subtle differences with scoping when using `alias` and `alias_method` but in this case it is unlikely to make a difference so you could just iterate over the methods you want to create an alias for:

```rb
class ProductPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  def update?
    creator? || admin?
  end

  %i(create? destroy? color?).each do |method|
    alias_method method, :update?
  end
end
```